# Facebook Oauth2.0

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am connecting my website to facebook using Facebook Graph API.

```
 public string WebResponseGet(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
        {
            StreamReader responseReader = null;
            string responseData = "";

            try
            {
                responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream().Close();
                responseReader.Close();
                responseReader = null;
            }
```

It gives me an excption Webexception unhandled by user
The remote server returned an error

Any tips on this?
I dont have a lot of programming experience but given this task.. so pls pardon me if its a question which I should be aware of

Thanks
SC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the Response property of the WebException you are thrown.  That will contain a message from Facebook which (hopefully) explains the issue

Comment: @user - are you sure you are looking at Response and not Message?

Comment: @user - and to be more specific, you need to call exception.Response.GetResponseStream and read that stream.  Alternatively, use a tool like Fiddler2 to view the HTTP traffic and examine the response that way.